# Prove: $\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R})\cap A = \mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R}\cap A)$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose set $A\subset X$, and $\mathscr{R}\subset 2^X$ is a ring of sets. If $\mathscr{E}$ is a family of sets, let $\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{E})$ denote the smallest $\sigma$-ring including $\mathscr{E}$, and
$$\mathscr{E}\cap A = \{E\cap A|E\in \mathscr{E}\}$$

Now I want to prove
$$\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R})\cap A = \mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R}\cap A)$$

The left side is obviously a $\sigma$-ring, thus is a superset of the right side. However, I don't know how to prove the other direction. From a larger view, is there any general method to prove a certain family is included in a generated ring or generated $\sigma$-ring? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the family of all $E$ such that $E \cap A \in \mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R}\cap A)$. Show that it is a $\sigma$-algebra and that it contains $\mathscr{R}$. If you can do it, please, don't forget to answer your own question below... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks André Caldas for the hint. The point is to construct the family
$$\mathscr{E}=\{E\subset X| E\cap A\in\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R}\cap A)\}$$
which I believe is a superset of $\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R})$.

To prove this, first $\mathscr{R}\subset\mathscr{E}$ because for each $F\in\mathscr{R}$ we have 
$$F\cap A\in\mathscr{R}\cap A\subset\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R}\cap A)$$
And $\mathscr{E}$ is a $\sigma$-ring because set intersection is distributive over set minus and countable intersection. So we get the conclusion.

Comment: It should be mentioned that $\mathscr{E}\cap A=\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R}\cap A)$ and so as Willard showed, this implies $\mathscr{R}_\sigma(\mathscr{R})\cap A\subset \mathscr{E}\cap A$ which finishes the proof.